# I have an INSTEAD OF trigger, but PostgreSQL still complains while I insert into view

Tags: postgresql, trigger, view, plpgsql

I have created a view and an INSTEAD OF trigger for inserting/ updating/ deleting from that view. Now I have tried to insert some data to the view, and PostgreSQL returns following error (translation from Czech: "chyba" = "error", "Stav SQL" = "SQL state"):

```
ERROR:  cannot insert into view "ukaz_lok"
DETAIL:  Views that return columns that are not columns of their base relation are not automatically updatable.
HINT:  To enable inserting into the view, provide an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger or an unconditional ON INSERT DO INSTEAD rule.
********** Chyba **********

ERROR: cannot insert into view "ukaz_lok"
Stav SQL: 55000
```

This happened before with some other INSTEAD OF triggers - this bug lasted just for some time (few hours? I don't remember exactly) and then PostgreSQL found the trigger. I tried various things (change the trigger, delete all triggers and views and creating them anew etc.), but I'm not sure what worked, just that something worked. **So how exactly to make the PostgreSQL recognize the trigger?**

I have PostgreSQL 9.3.4 and pgAdmin III 1.18.1 on Windows XP 32 bit. Just in case it was caused by something in the code, here it is:

```
CREATE TABLE lokalita
(
  kod_lok text NOT NULL,
  nazev text NOT NULL,
  katastr text NOT NULL,
  presnost integer NOT NULL,
  stred geometry(Point,4326) NOT NULL,
  rozsah geometry(Polygon,4326),
  CONSTRAINT pk_lok PRIMARY KEY (kod_lok),
  CONSTRAINT fk_pro_pr FOREIGN KEY (presnost)
      REFERENCES pro_presnost (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ukaz_lok AS
  SELECT
    l.kod_lok AS _kod,
    l.nazev AS _nazev,
    l.katastr AS _katastr,
    l.presnost AS _presnost,
    50.0 AS _sirka,
    14.0 AS _delka
  FROM lokalita l;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION osetri_lok() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
  IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
    INSERT INTO lokalita (kod_lok, nazev, katastr, presnost, stred)
    VALUES(
      NEW._kod,
      NEW._nazev,
      NEW._katastr,
      NEW._presnost,
      ST_GeomFromText('POINT('|| NEW.delka ||' '|| NEW.sirka ||')', 4326)
    );
  ELSIF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
    UPDATE lokalita 
    SET
      nazev = NEW._nazev,
      katastr = NEW._katastr,
      presnost = NEW._presnost,
      stred = ST_GeomFromText('POINT('|| NEW.delka ||' '|| NEW.sirka ||')', 4326)
    WHERE lod_lok = OLD._kod;
  ELSIF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN
    DELETE FROM lokalita WHERE kod_lok = OLD._kod;
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER osetri_lok
INSTEAD OF DELETE ON ukaz_lok
FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE osetri_lok();

INSERT INTO ukaz_lok (_kod, _nazev, _katastr, _presnost, _delka, _sirka)
  VALUES(
  'Kote2',
  'Kotěhůlky 2',
  'Kotěhůlky',
  2,
  14.060316,
  50.432044
);
```

Comment: Hint: to get English error messages in your session, run `SET lc_messages='C'`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a trigger `INSTEAD OF DELETE` in your code, but none `INSTEAD OF` **`INSERT`**. Create that, too.

You *can* make that a trigger `INSTEAD OF INSERT OR DELETE`, but I'd suggest separate trigger functions for `INSERT` and `DELETE` and separate triggers. Simplifies the function code (no more need for `IF TG_OP =`  etc.).

Also consider [this quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/trigger-definition.html):

> A row-level `INSTEAD OF` trigger should either return `NULL` to
> indicate that it did not modify any data from the view's underlying
> base tables, or it should return the view row that was passed in (the
> `NEW` row for `INSERT` and `UPDATE` operations, or the `OLD` row for
> `DELETE` operations). A nonnull return value is used to signal that
> the trigger performed the necessary data modifications in the view.
> This will cause the count of the number of rows affected by the
> command to be incremented. For `INSERT` and `UPDATE` operations only,
> the trigger may modify the `NEW` row before returning it. This will
> change the data returned by `INSERT RETURNING` or `UPDATE RETURNING`,
> and is useful when the view will not show exactly the same data that
> was provided.

Comment: Damned copy + paste. I used a DELETE trigger as a template and forgot this detail. For my other INSTEAD OF triggers, I have this separate (also because the procedures are large either); thanks for a hint for good practice anyway.

Comment: @Pavel: You're welcome. Also consider the added quote.